# Confused about <img> tag in HTML: Is it empty, and why the attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I'm puzzled by the  tag in HTML. People say it's an empty tag, but it can have attributes like src, alt, width, height, and id. Can someone clear up whether it's truly empty and shed light on why it supports these attributes?

Is it really a empty tag?

Comment: Who says these things? It's a self closing tag, a tag that doesn't have a content block, sure, but I don't see why it would have content at all, as it's not displaying any textual information, so... This is a strange question. Also seems to attract everyone with no rep.

Answer (score 0):

It's "empty" in the sense that it doesn't have content within its opening and closing tags. For example, the `<p>` has text between its opening and closing tags (`<p>Lorum ipsum dolor</p>`). For an `<img>`, you don't have a closing tag (`</img>`), and its behavior is defined entirely by its attributes (`width`, `height`, `src`, etc).

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#technical_summary)

Answer (score 0):

In html we consider a tag empty tag when it does not have **closing tag** , because img tag does not have closing tag so we say it empty tag. Empty tag does not mean the tag don't have any **attribute** it means the tag does not have **closing tag.**

Answer (score 0):

No  tag is not empty, it have attributes

- The src attribute is required, and contains the path to the image you want to embed.
- The alt attribute holds a textual replacement for the image, which is mandatory and incredibly useful for accessibility — screen readers read the attribute value out to their users so they know what the image means. Alt text is also displayed on the page if the image can't be loaded for some reason: for example, network errors, content blocking, or linkrot.

There are many other attributes to achieve various purposes:

Referrer/CORS control for security and privacy: see crossorigin and referrerpolicy.
Use both width and height to set the intrinsic size of the image, allowing it to take up space before it loads, to mitigate content layout shifts.
Responsive image hints with sizes and srcset (see also the  element and our Responsive images tutorial).
 [tag documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

Answer (score 0):

The concept of `empty tag`/`void tag`/`self-closing tag` is that which **doesn't contain** any **children element**. So, you can consider it as a `leaf tag` that doesn't have even the text inside it. And as these tags don't support child elements, they don't have a corresponding closing tag either. Examples are- `<img>`, `<br>`, `<hr>`, `<meta>`, `<link>` etc.

In **HTML5**, even we don't need to close those tags. By default **according to the HTML5 specification**, there are **15 empty tags**, these are also known as `void tags` or `self-closing` because they do not have a corresponding closing tag and they cannot contain other elements.

[**Note**: **Attributes** inside a tag, **help us to define their behavior & view**. Different tags support different attributes. But tag itself an empty/void identifies from the capability of accepting a children element or not.]

Answer (score -2):

every tag in html is not empty tag you can add css, id, and classes to them so called attributes.THere is no such thing in html like empty tag yes there are tag who
are self closed

ex  
 ,,